# In sharepoint programming is it better to use CAML or Code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, caml

I am about to start creating a sharepoint features.  I want to know what the recommended approach to creating lists, columns, content types etc is?

CAML (xml etc) or Code object models?

I have no problem doing either approach.  Are there any major cons to any of these approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are *required* for a robust solution. Both are useful. Neither [entirely] replaces the other.

[CAML queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521.aspx) are *required* to efficiently query most SP datasources efficiently, such as Lists. On the other hand non-query CAML can be used to [declarative configure *many* SharePoint artifacts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms426449.aspx).

The direct OM ([SharePoint Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx)) is very useful for programatically iterating/updating many things; including the results from various CAML queries! The PowerShell cmd-lets also expose the OM for easy "inspection" of the current state of the Farm, etc. Scripts can also take advantage of this when needing to create many things - e.g. webs - from a common "template" with slight variations.

In addition, there are many operations via the OM which is *not* possible with CAML. For instance, Timer Job Definitions cannot be configured with just CAML.

However, writing a Feature Receiver to modify SP artifacts can be problematic, especially if changes must be done later: the revisions must then also be managed from the receiver - ick! For supported SP artificacts, **always use CAML unless there is a reason not to**. Do not complicate things without very good reason.

Don't fight SharePoint. Each task is different. Use the correct (and hopefully "approved") approach to make life easier.